# Ruby array to hash with dates as keys

Tags: ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  ["20180630", "14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180630", "12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"],
  ["20180629", "17:20", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "16:30", "(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "09:29", "(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]
]
```

What I would like to have as an output is a hash where the date serves as the key:

```
{
  "20180630": [["14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"],["12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]],
  "20180629": [[...],[...],[...]]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you have written to solve this problem that you are having trouble with and explain a little bit more what your *precise* problem is with the code you have written to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable#group_by` will give you the hash-of-arrays transformation, then it's just a matter of removing the redundant column from the resulting values:

```
hash = input_array.group_by(&:first)
hash.each { |_, list| list.each(&:shift) }
hash
```

(note that modifies the original arrays; you'll need to adjust to a version with more copying and less mutation if that's a problem)

Comment: If you don't care about preserving the original array, then simply `input_array.group_by(&:shift)`

Comment: If you believe @Sergio's comment (which replaces your three lines with one) represents an improvement, I suggest you edit your answer accordingly and thank Sergio in a comment. If you want readers to know what you had before, do so in the same comment, not in the answer. Our duty is to readers, who care less about attribution than content. I suggest you treat your answers like passages from an article or book.

Comment: When I read your answer my immediate reaction was, "why `shift`?", which modifies that receiver, rather than `drop(1)`, which does not? When the asker does not state that the receiver is to be mutated we should assume that it is not to be touched. You could have written, `hash.each { |_, list| list.map { |a| a.drop(1)}`, which has a few more character than the cute `shift` code, but that's irrelevant. Alternatively: `hash.transform_values {|v| v.map { |a| a.drop(1) }}`. [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) made its debut in Ruby v2.4.

Comment: @CarySwoveland while a neat simplification (+1), I didn't think it helpful to the reader to conflate the grouping and the adjustment of the value. And as your answer shows, it's a bit more complicated than `s/shift/drop/`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to build the desired hash. Neither mutates the given array (`arr`).

```
arr = [
  ["20180630", "14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180630", "12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"],
  ["20180629", "17:20", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "16:30", "(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"], 
  ["20180629", "09:29", "(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]
]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| (h[a.first] ||= []) << a.drop(1) }
  #=> {"20180630"=>[["14:49", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"],
  #                 ["12:22", "google", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]],
  #   "20180629"=>[["17:20", "google", "iOS", "Safari", "1"],
  #                ["16:30", "(direct)", "iOS", "Safari", "1"],
  #                ["09:29", "(direct)", "Android", "Chrome", "2"]]}
```

A variant is the following.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |a,h| h[a.first] << a.drop(1) }
```

Alternatively, one can use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h.update(a.first=>[a.drop(1)]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
```